# Customize a Php mail with html

Tags: php, html, email

I want to customize an php email with some html but I'm struggling with that...

After submit my form i receive the email but happen **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z98p.png)**

I was following this **[tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)**

I put the code i used.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Alright, lets send the email already!
if ( empty( $errorString ) ) {

    $mailbody .= '<html><body>';
    $mailbody .= '<img src="//http://xxxx/xxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg" alt="Website Change Request" />';
    $mailbody .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';

    $mailbody .= __('Nome:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $clientname . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Email:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $email . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Chegada:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $arrive . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Saída:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $depart . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Adultos:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $guests . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Crianças:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $children . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Quarto:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $room->post_title . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Mensagem:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $message . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Hora do Check-in (hh:mm):', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $timeguest . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Contacto:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $contactguest . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Autorização:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $autorizo . "\n";
    $mailbody .= __('Cama Extra:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $camaextra . "\n";
    $mailbody .= "</table>";
    $mailbody .= "</body></html>";

    mail($to, $mailbody, $headers); 

    // If you want to receive the email using the address of the sender, comment the next $emailSent = ... line
    // and uncomment the one after it.
    // Keep in mind the following comment from the wp_mail() function source:
    /* If we don't have an email from the input headers default to wordpress@$sitename
    * Some hosts will block outgoing mail from this address if it doesn't exist but
    * there's no easy alternative. Defaulting to admin_email might appear to be another
    * option but some hosts may refuse to relay mail from an unknown domain. See
    * http://trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5007.
    */
    //$emailSent = wp_mail(ci_setting('booking_form_email'), get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Booking form', 'ci_theme'), $mailbody);
    $emailSent = wp_mail(ci_setting('booking_form_email'), get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Formulário de Reserva','theme-text-domain', 'ci_theme'), $mailbody, 'From: "'.$clientname.'" <'.$email.'>');
    $emailSent2 = wp_mail( $email, __('Booking Inquiry','theme-text-domain', 'ci_theme'), __('Thank you so much for your interest in Hotel Aveiro Center! We will get back to you within 24 hours to answer your request.','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),'From: Hotel Aveiro Center <xxxx@xxxx>');

}
```

Comment: Customize the mail ?? You want to have your own `mailbody` already you are doing it. What you want to change in your mail ?

Comment: First of all, what is the problem? "I'm struggling" doesn't give us much to work with. Also, you are appending values to the `$mailbody` variable, but in this code snippet you haven't defined it. You need to define it (`$mailbody = NULL;`) before you can append.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. Im new with the php. I want to do that https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/before-and-after.png (after)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example I have done .

```
//build email to be sent
    $to = $email;
    $subject = $site_url;
    $subject .= ": Activate Your Account";

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Account Activation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>Account Activation</h3>
    <p>Dear ".$user.", thank you for registering at ".$site_url.".</p>
    <p>Please click on the link below to activate your account:</p>
    <a href='".$site_url."/confirm_user_reg.php?activation_key=".$activation_key."'>http://www.".$site_url."</a>.
    <p>If the above link does not work, copy and paste the below URL to your browser's address bar:</p>
    <p><i>http://www.".$site_url."/confirm_user_reg.php?activation_key=".$activation_key."</i></p><br/>
    <p>If you did not initiate this request, simply disregard this email, and we're sorry for bothering you.</p>
    <br/><br/>
    <p>Sincerely,</p>
    <p>The ".$site_url." Team.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```